# Rails toggle function hidden by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the "toggle" function in my code to show / hide a div.  I want it to be hidden by default though.  How should I do this.

Here's the line of code:

```
<%= link_to_function "+ Add a comment", "$('comment-form').toggle()" %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css:

```
.hidden { display: none;}
```

And give your `div` the `hidden` class

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done UJS by having

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $('comment-form').hide();
 })
</script>
```

Somewhere on the page. This will let you also run many different javascript/jquery calls once the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding a little on the previous 2 answers:

In your template

```
<div class="commment_form hidden">
<!-- Comment form markup -->
</div>
<%= link_to"+ Add a comment", "#", :id => "comment_link" %>
```

In your css

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

In your application.js

```
$(document(ready) {
  $('#comment_link').click(function() {
    $('.comment_form').toggle();
  });
});
```

I'm going from memory, so my apologies if the code isn't perfect!\